# Is it possible to have images auto-resize in a CSS grid while maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: css, image

For example this produces an image that fits it's container if the container has type block:

```
#image {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

However it doesn't work if the image is part of a grid that has fixed sized rows (here's [a plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/6sTDFg4UcpyiSruwjvbg?p=preview) to see it in action) e.g.:

```
<style>
    #container {
       display: grid;
       grid-auto-columns: 0.3fr;
       grid-auto-rows: 80px;
    }

    .image {
        border: 1px solid black;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    }

    .image:nth-child(1) {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
    }

    .image:nth-child(2) {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 2;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1366x768">
    <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1366x768">
</div>
```

In this example both images go outside of their box, I would've expected both images to behave like they were in individual containers like this:

```
#container {
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Basically my question is, is there a way I can style the images so that they can scale to fit any grid cell (regardless of whether the cell uses `auto` or fixed size) so that they automatically shrink to fit within the cell while also maintaining their aspect ratio (in the same way that they can shrink in the block container)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=750631) rather than something I was doing wrong with `max-height` so there's no further action on this.

Answer (score -1):

i think you need use the type of image (like png etc ... ) and use property background-size: cover; 
the important is the image type some type image when scale will broken , you need image vector for scale

Comment: SVG is irrelevant, the images are just plain images already. Basically there's a grid that displays the images small in a grid but then they can be zoomed in groups. In the zoomed view they need to fit within the viewport so absolute values for `grid-row-auto` needs to be used (e.g. `1fr` ) but in the table `auto` is fine (the columns aren't auto but whatever). |

`background-size: cover` has pretty much the same issues from what I tried of it.